# Is java imported class included in bytecode

Tags: java

This is a 2 part question about java import.

1. Is an imported class included in the output class file when compiled ?
2. Does an imported class need to be available in a jar or as a class file at run time ?

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Is an imported class included in the output class file when compiled ?

No.

> 2) Does an imported class need to be available in a jar or as a class file at run time ?

yes

(but it may be in another `jar` file than the importing class).

---

> So the run time class could be different to the compile time class or is there some checking done to ensure they are the same ? – mccool

Yes.

It could be a different Version of that class as long as it has the same *full qualified name* and the methods called on it have the same *signature*.

This is part of the *polymorphism* feature of an OO language implemented by *late binding*.

Comment: So the run time class could be different to the compile time class or is there some checking done to ensure they are the same ?

Comment: @mccool depends on what you are trying to achive. If you replace a class inside a jar with a new version and that new version replaces some method with new ones (name or arguments differ) the JVM will throw an appropriate exception. This usually happens if certain dependencies require other dependencies of a certain version though you provide differen ones (= JAR hell)

Comment: So there must be some short description of the class in the bytecode produced by the compiler, but in theory the run time could run a method which differs in its detailed code ?

Comment: Thanks all, I asked the opening question in this forum because I cannot recall finding it explained in any java book or tutorial I have read.

Comment: Just nitpicking: writing an import statement like `import my.package.Data;` without using any `Data` in your code only gives a compiler warning and doesn't need the `my.package.Data` class to be present at runtime.

Comment: @Timothy Truckle  That link  seems to be about access control, whereas I wanted to know where the classes were stored -  compile time or runtime

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff thanks! I'm still happy nobody mentiones that the other class still must be s *subtype* of the type of the variable it is stored in or anny parameter it is passed to...